# What does it mean when a webpage says refresh is disabled?

Tags: web-browser

https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?rh1dkyd2:

> To safeguard your privacy we have disabled the browser's "reload" or "refresh" facility while you are in sensitive areas of our web site. Reloading pages will function normally once you have left this area . . . but until then please refrain from "reloading" pages.

I'm not understand what that page is trying to say? It says refresh is disabled but I do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and the browser refreshed..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, Mr. Gibson is a bit of a tool when it comes to security. The appropriate term is charlatan.

His secure pages cause the pages to be cached locally, so when you hit refresh it doesn't make a web request, but just pulls the html from local storage.

He didn't "disable" refreshing, he modified the default behaviour of a page request. You can still refresh the page, and you can make the request again.

It really doesn't do much for security because the sensitive stuff is now sitting in your cache for a really long time. It isn't any more secure than making the request again.

Comment: 'Tool' hahahaha- :)

Comment: @RoryAlsop explain your comment

Comment: @Pacerier - Steve's description of Mr Gibson - have a wee read of http://attrition.org/errata/charlatan/steve_gibson/